# PC Sometimes Won't Connect to Internet (Solved) Dell Inspiron 530

Tags: windows-7, networking, router

My PC is a Dell Inspiron 530 with Windows 7 Home Premium. Sometimes when I boot or reboot it, it won't connect to the local network. I'm usually able to use the troubleshooting built into Windows to fix it, but it doesn't tell me the details of the problem other than

1. “Local Area Connection” doesn’t have a valid IP configuration, and
2. The default gateway is not available.

It only fixes it temporarily.

When the computer is restarted, the problem often is back.  I've also noticed that I'm not able to connect to my router's configuration window by entering the router's IP address in any browser, although I'm able to connect to the router's configuration window with another computer.   I've gone to the command prompt as administrator and tried doing ipconfig commands but that doesn't fix it.  When I do `ipconfig /renew`, I get “An error occurred while renewing interface Local Area Connection : unable to contact your DHCP server.  Request has timed out.”

I've also tried pinging the router from the command prompt and it can't be pinged at all.  I've also updated the driver for the built in network interface but there's no change.   This computer came with Windows Vista and on the Dell website, they don't have drivers for Windows 7.   There are Windows 7 drivers available on other websites though.   I've also used iobit Driver Booster and Windows Update to replace all of the drivers, but there's no change.  I just got this computer so I don't know if Windows 7 always had this problem on this computer or not.

Comment: Summarising your post. Sometimes your computer does not connect to the **local network**. You tried solving it, possibly using the right commands but the output of those commands (which might tell us what is going on) is not posted. Recommended solution. 1) When it does work do write down the information from IP config. 2) When it does not work write it down. Look at the difference. It is probably something like '192.168.1.100/24 with GW 192.168.1.1' when ti works and some fake number (169.something.something.something when it does not work).

Comment: Next, try to find out why it did not work. Log files are your friend. Also write down if you are using wired or wireless (and if wired, same cable? If wireless, same position near the wireless access point) etc etc.

Comment: Yesterday it wouldn't connect to the internet at all.   Today I connected a different cat cable and it was almost instantly connected to the internet.   With the other cable, even when it did connect it took about 20 to 30 seconds before it would connect.   I'll see how it goes with this cable.

Comment: The problem is back again today so I'll begin doing as you've said to do.

Comment: I installed another hard drive and installed windows 7 on it.   The computer still has the same problem, so I think it's a hardware problem.   Is it possible that a poor driver might work sometimes and not other times?

Comment: Technically possible, but unlikely. A broken cable, a loose connector etc is more likely.

Comment: I installed a network pci card and it's having no problems so far.

Comment: If you feel inclined there are two more test: 1) Check the old NICs port. Anything loose? Anything broken?  2) You could use a completely different OS (and thus different drivers).   But I at this point I am guessing HW problem with the original NIC and same results on any OS (e.g. windows, BSD, Linux, hackintosch, ...)

Comment: A week has gone by and there has been no problem with the new NIC card.   I had already checked the old NIC (which is integrated into the motherboard).   I checked the gold pins and none are bent and they are clean.   Nothing is loose.   I installed Windows Vista, which is the original operating system for this system.   The old NIC still has the exact same problem.   The new NIC has no problem at all.   I'm concluding this thread as solved, with the problem being faulty integrated NIC.  Thanks for your help Hennes.

Comment: When I'm attempting to sign in with Skype for Windows, it tells me that I've tried to sign in with the wrong password too many times and I have to fill in a captcha.    It's difficult to tell if some of the captcha letters are uppercase of lowercase.   I've tried signing in with my original password and with all of my changed passwords and I keep getting the same error saying I've tried signing in with the wrong password.    When I reset the password, it changes the password in my hotmail account and in my skype account.